# Can you help me with this curve problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider the curve defined by the equation
$$y + \cos y = x+1$$ 
for $0\le y\le 2\pi$.

Find the point $(x,y)$ on the curve at which the tangent line is parallel to the line $y= (1/2)x = 2$.

Answer (score 2):

Deriving implicitly the equation of the curve with respect to $x$, we have
$$y'-y' \sin y=1$$
If we want the tangent line to be parallel to $y=\frac{x}{2}$, we must have $y'=\frac{1}{2}$, so
$$\frac{1}{2}(1-\sin y)=1 \Rightarrow\sin y = -1 \Rightarrow y=\frac{3\pi}{2}$$
Substituting in the equation
$$\frac{3\pi}{2}+\cos \frac{3\pi}{2}=x+1 \Rightarrow x=\frac{3\pi}{2}-2$$
So, the point desired is $P=\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}-2,\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)$.